# Ruby: Clean code for checking nil /false conditional statement?

Tags: ruby

I always meet this Ruby problem, I want to write it more cleanly.

```
var a can be nil
a.value can also be nil
a.value has possible true or false value

if (not a.nil?) && (not a.value.nil?) && a.value == false
  puts "a value is not available"
else
  puts "a value is true"
end
```

The problem is that the conditional statement is too clumsy and hard to read.
How can I improve the checking `nil` and `false` conditional statement?

Thanks, I am a Ruby newbie

Comment: Have you check my edited answer???

Comment: If `a.value` being `nil` would raise an error, then why do you put that in the condition? It does not make sense because the error would be raised anyway.

Comment: it is because i am going to check a.value == false, if a.value is nil, it cannot check if that condition (undefined method for a.value), and raise exception

Comment: Um, no, you'll only get an undefined method error if `a` is nil, not if `a.value` is nil.

Comment: Or if `a` is a class and `value` is not defined.

Comment: Does variable 'a' really have `value` method if it can be `nil`? Or `true` or `false`?

Comment: it may not have that method

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ruby on rails has an extension called `try` which allows you to write:

```
 if a.try(:value) == false
```

which is very clean. Without `try`, you can just write

```
 if a && a.value == false
```

If `a.value` is nil, it is not false, so that is ok :)

If it is possible that `a.value` is not defined (which would raise an exception), I would write that as follows:

```
if a && a.respond_to?(:value) && a.value == false
```

[UPDATE: after ruby 2.3]

Since ruby 2.3 there is an even shorter version:

```
if a&.value == false
```

which is almost equivalent to `a.try(:value)` (but is pure ruby). Differences:

- if `value` does not exist, the `&.` operator will throw, `try` will just return nil (preferable or not?)(note: `try!` would also throw).
- when cascading `try` or `&.` they also handle `false` differently. This follows logically from previous difference, `try` will return nil, while `&.` will throw because `false` knows no methods :P

Comment: To be precise, this answer is not equivalent to the OP's code. If OP had defined `false.value`, and that has the possibility of being `false`, then the result would be different. But I assumed that may not be the case and gave +1 here.

Comment: You are nitpicking. It is standard practice to check for nil this way. Unfortunately this does not work if the value could be false. This will bite you when doing something like `a.value ||= true` --> which will always set it to true, because false and nil will return false. But in this case it is just fine.

Comment: All valid points, but it's worth noting that if you get too defensive in your programming you end up hiding actual errors. If your method only accepts an `a` value that's either `nil` or defined with a `value` property exposed, you're not responsible for handling oddball cases where `value` is not present. Let it blow up. The caller's responsible for making the correct call.

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve it in more compacted way using Safe Navigation Operator (`&.`):

`if a&.value == false`

Source : http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/

Comment: *Available since Ruby 2.3.0

Answer (score 2):

```
  if a && a.value!=false
     puts "a value is true"
  else
     puts "a value is not available"         
  end


  or just 

  puts a && a.value!=false ? "a value is true" : "a value is not available"
```

Comment: `puts a && a.value ? "a value is true" : "a value is not available"` cause in ruby `nil` and `false` in an argument considered as `false`

Comment: (Pure) Ruby does not have a method `blank?`. Also, this is not equivalent to the OP's code. This code puts `"a value is not available"` when `a.value` is `nil`, but the OP's code puts `"a value is true"`.

Comment: @sawa :- I remove blank? already please check my edited answer and comment on it

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and cleanest way is to flip it and reverse it. Check for the `truthy` value rather than the `falsey` values

```
if a && a.value
  puts "a value is true"
else
  puts "a value is not available"
end
```

Of course in `Rails` you could do it either way by using `blank?` or `present?`

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is redundant. If `a.value` is to be `false`, then it would not be `nil`.

```
if a.nil?.! && a.value == false
  puts "a value is not available"
else
  puts "a value is true"
end
```

Comment: If it is `false`, it cannot be `nil`.

Comment: if a.value is nil, it will throw exception

Comment: Then, why do you have that in the condition?

Comment: Whoa, I didn't know about `Boolean#!`.

Comment: @ChrisHeald It is `Object#!`. I think it was introduced in Ruby 2.0. It makes chaining in condition easier.

Comment: yea, u are right, i think i have sth misunderstood. it will not throw exception

Comment: Having the unary prefix `!` operator translate into a message send as opposed to being bultin was introduced in Ruby 1.9.0.

Answer (score 0):

This will always return a boolean, if nil it will return false; if false it returns false; if true returns true. Try it out, it's nice and short:

`!!a.try(:value) == false`